# Conditional on Playa field with var_prefix

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

Is there any reason this conditional wouldn't work?

```
{standard_page_events var_prefix="cat"}
    {cat:event_category_description}
    {exp:playa:coparents var_prefix="event" channel="events" child_id="{cat:entry_id}"}
        {if {event:count} == 1}<div class="banded"></div><hr>{/if}
    {/exp:playa:coparents}
{/standard_page_events}
```

Comment: Try `{event:if count == 1}`.

Answer (score 3):

Brandon's solution worked great! Thanks!

```
{event:if count == 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ian's suggestion worked great for me. Here was my working code

```
{if '{thirdorder:static_map_3rd_order}'} 
    <img src="{thirdorder:static_map_3rd_order}" alt="{thirdorder:title}" style="padding:10px;" width="100%"/>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wrap it in quotes. Try this:

```
{if '{event:count}' == '1'}<div class="banded"></div><hr>{/if}
```